# How to pickle an object of a class B (having many variables) that inherits from A, that defines __setstate__ and __getstate__

Tags: python, inheritance, pickle

**My problem is:**

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        #init
    def __setstate__(self,state):
        #A __setstate__ code here            
    def __getstate__(self):
        #A __getstate__ code here
        return state

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        #creates many object variables here
```

A is from an external library.

**Hard solution**

This I would like to avoid

When pickling B, pickle of course uses class A's `__setstate__`, `__getstate__` methods, so in order for pickle to work I should do something like this:

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        #creates many object variables here

    def __setstate__(self,state)
        A.__setstate__(self,state)
        #B __setstate__ code here
        #getting various variables from state for example
        self._a0 = state['a0']
        self._a1 = state['a1']
        #...
        self._a100 = state['a100']
        self._a101 = state['a101']

    def __getstate__(self):
        state = A.__getstate__(self)
        #B __setstate__ code here
        #filling state with various variables  
        #getting various variables from state for example
        state['a0'] =  self._a0
        state['a1'] =  self._a1
        #...
        state['a100'] =  self._a100
        state['a101'] =  self._a101           
        return state
```

**My question is:**

How can I avoid defining `__setstate__` and `__getstate__` in B so that pickle does the job of pickling variables by itself? 
All variables in B are of type that pickle may pickle(handle) by itself.
So if B didn't inherit from A, it would be possible with good results:

```
b = B()
path = 'path.temp'
fout = open(path,'w')
pickler = pickl.Pickler(fout)

pickler.dump(b)
fout.close()

fin = open(path,'r')
upickler = pickl.Unpickler(fin)
b = unpickler.load()
fin.close()
#b has all variables
```

**The obvious solution**

```
class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        #creates many object variables here
        a = A()
```

However I would like B to inherit from A.
Any idea how to solve this or at least automate pickling/unpickling variables in B?

**The workaround solution:**

As for automating pickling in the **Hard Solution**

Add to B a dictionary holding variables to pickle:

```
class B(A):
    __picklableObjects__ = {'_a0', '_a1', ... ,'_a101'}

    def __init__(self):
        #creates many object variables here
        A.__init__(self)
        self._a0 = ...
        ...
        self._a101 = ...

    @staticmethod
    def getPicklableObjects():
        return B.__picklableObjects__

    def __setstate__(self,state):
        A.__setstate__(self,state)
        for po in B.getPicklableObjects():
           __dict__[po] = state[po]

    def __getstate__(self):
        state = A.__getstate__(self)
        for po in B.getPicklableObjects():
            state[po] = copy.deepcopy(__dict__[po])
        return state
```

Any other ideas?

**A's library:**

Ok so for any of you interested A is graph_tool.Graph:
[A src code](http://projects.skewed.de/graph-tool/browser/src/graph_tool/__init__.py)

```
line 786: class Graph(object)

...

line 1517: __getstate__

...

line 1533: __setstate__
```

Comment: Do you have access to the code of `A`? I usually write my `__getstate__` methods in some kind of 'opt-out' way, where I copy the instances `__dict__` property and delete or modify unpickable entries. This would nicely carry over to the daughter class.

Comment: Yes, I have access to A. A is in an external library. Modifying A code would be problematic as I am not certain how it would impact rest of that library. So in other words you would propose something like in 'The workaround solution'?

Comment: Have you considered using other serializers?

Comment: I was more suggesting to modify the code of `A` in order to don't break the inheritance. I find it more convenient, if a class by default returns everything from its `__getstate__` method and only excludes problematic properties. If you would be able to modify `A` accordingly, you wouldn't need any code in `B` at all.

Comment: I wanted to leave modifying A's code as an action of last resort. As A is in an external python library. Furthermore I would rather sacrifice inheriting from A rather than modifying A.

Answer (score 4):

According to the documentation, when `__getstate__` isn't defined, the instance's `__dict__` is pickled so maybe, you can use this to define your own state methods as a combination of the `A` methods and the instance's `__dict__`:

```
import pickle

class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 'A state'

    def __getstate__(self):
        return {'a': self.a}

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        self.a = state['a']

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        A.__init__(self)
        self.b = 'B state'

    def __getstate__(self):
        a_state = A.__getstate__(self)
        b_state = self.__dict__
        return (a_state, b_state)

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        a_state, b_state = state
        self.__dict__ = b_state
        A.__setstate__(self, a_state)

b = pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(B()))
print b.a
print b.b
```

Comment: Ok but what about the fact, that A defines __setstate__, __getstate__ in order not to pickle some things (don't know what they are, and don't know why it is --- the class is pretty much complicated). The solution you presented in __getstate__ duplicates variables, or at least properties of A (they are in a_state and b_state). I was also wondering, that with this solution I should check A's code thoroughly for potential blowback of pickling in b_state variables that are not pickled by A and them setting them. As some of them are overwritten by A.__setstate__ some not.

Comment: @user779686 That's correct, part of the state in `b_state` is duplicated in `a_state`. Also, the ordering in `B.__getstate__` and `B.__setstate__` gives preference to `A` methods. However, I'd say that's appropriate to avoid breaking `A` behaviour.

Comment: I'll experiment with this solution and see whether there are some negative consequences concerning A and potentially unpickling potentially unwanted variables/states.

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior of Pickle is `__getstate__` is not defined is to pickle the contents of the objects `__dict__` attribute - that is where the instance attributes are stored.

Therefore it looks like in your case, all you need to do is to make `A`'s get and set state to  preserve the values found in `self.__dict__` and restore then at `__setstate__` - this should preserve the instance variables of all instances of subclasses of A as well.

Comment: Changing A has a good chance breaking anything else depending on A.